# Force 8 digits in phone number WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Denmark all phone numbers are 8 digits. We'd like to force all orders to be 8 digits to prevent bugs and others with delivery. Never less, never more. When not 8 digits they should get a warning.

```
// You can add a custom placeholder to add a hint for your CUs what you expect
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields2' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields2( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Add 8 digits';

    return $fields;
}

/****************************************************************/
/* VALIDATION FOR PHONE FIELD THIS WILL THROW AN ERROR MESSAGE  */
/****************************************************************/

/**
 * Process the checkout
 **
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies
    if ( ! (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/D', $_POST['billing_phone'] ))){
        wc_add_notice( "Phone number must be 8 digits"  ,'error' );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. The number can still be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use strlen on your post. Then evaluate if it is equal to the length you want.

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
  global $woocommerce;

  // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies
  $len = strlen($_POST['billing_phone']); 
  if($len !== 8){     
    wc_add_notice( "Phone number must be 8 digits"  ,'error' );
  }
}
```

If you also want it to match number, use `is_numeric()` or `!is_numeric()`

```
$len = strlen($_POST['billing_phone']);   
if($len !== 8)){
  wc_add_notice( "Phone number must be 8 digits"  ,'error' );
  if(!is_numeric($_POST['billing_phone'])){           
    wc_add_notice( "Phone number must be number"  ,'error' );
  }
}
```

You can also set your input as type `tel` and add a pattern if there is specific pattern used in Denmark, this will help to format before submission on browsers that support html 5

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{8}" required>
```

OUTPUT ERROR WHEN NUMBER LESS THAN 8:

[image]

OUTPUT ERROR WHEN MORE THAN 8:

[image]

OUTPUT ERROR WHEN NOT A NUMBER:

[image]

Comment: When added, I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: use -> `if(!is_numeric($_POST['billing_phone']))' the code was missing a parentheses

Comment: `I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ')'`, this means there is likely a missing closing parentheses or an additional one too many, or a closing semi colon is missing. Does it give you a reference line to check?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for still looking into it. Still no help. I get the error for this line: if($len !== 8)){ 

https://imgur.com/a/R3jLa0C - see here.

Comment: There's no error, if I write it like this, but nothing happens in the checkout (i can put any number): https://codeshare.io/5wLwbK